# Passing unique_ptr<int[]> to a function

Tags: arrays, function, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int[]> addElement(int *myNumbers, int sizeOfArray);
void printArray(int * arr_ptr, int sizeOfArray);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int myNumbers[SIZE] = {18, 27, 3, 14, 95};

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> newCopy(new int[SIZE]);
    newCopy = addElement(myNumbers, SIZE);

    std::cout << "myNumbers: ";
    printArray(myNumbers, SIZE);

    std::cout << "newCopy: ";
    printArray(newCopy, SIZE + 1);


    return 0;
}

std::unique_ptr<int[]> addElement(int *myNumbers, int sizeOfArray)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> newArray(new int[sizeOfArray + 1]);

    newArray[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        newArray[i + 1] = myNumbers[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}

void printArray(int * arr_ptr, int sizeOfArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr_ptr[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

When trying to call `printArray(newCopy, SIZE + 1);` I get the compiler error `cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<int []>' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void printArray(int*, int)'`

I have read several similar questions on here yet I can't seem to find the solution to passing the `int[]` and the `unique_ptr<int[]>` to the `printArray` function.

---

```
std::cout << "newCopy: ";
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE + 1; i++)
{
    std::cout << newCopy[i] << ' ';
}
```

Does what I would like

```
std::cout << "newCopy: ";
printArray(newCopy, SIZE + 1);
```

to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying to call `printArray(newCopy, SIZE + 1);` I get the compiler error `cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<int []>' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void printArray(int*, int)'`

This is because you try to pass `std::unique_ptr<int []>` object into a function that instead expects a `int*`. But `std::unique_ptr<int []>` is a different type than `int*` and not implicitly convertible.

Solution: You should pass an `int*` instead. The `std::unique_ptr` is simply a wrapper around the bare pointer. If you take a look at the documentation of `std::unique_ptr`, you'll find that it has a member function `std::unique_ptr::get` that

> returns a pointer to the managed object